# How to open a div with this code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        $.fn.colorbox({href:"res/homer.jpg", open:true});  
    }, 1500);
});
```

This little code opens a window where is the Picture (homer.jpg), but I want to open DIV for example div with id: #examplediv

what should I change in code?

Comment: Do you mean 'open' is popup??

Comment: Could you please further explain this question I'm having a hard time understanding it.

Comment: $.colorbox({html:$('#examplediv').html()});

Comment: **Unclear what you're asking:**
*Please clarify your specific problem or **add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.** As it's currently written, **it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.***

Answer (score 0):

Use this code snippet to add it though you have to change a few things:

```
$('.element').attr('id', 'newID');
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

*Sorry, but your question was not clear*

**HTML**

```
<div id="#examplediv"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#examplediv{
   position: absolute;
   margin: 200px;
   padding: 5px;
   border: 2px solid #000;
}
#examplediv > img{
   width: 120px; height: 120px;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#examplediv').html('<img src="res/homer.jpg" alt="" />');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Capture the HTML of the div you want and then feed that as the argument to the colorbox call:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var myhtml = $('#examplediv').html();
        $.colorbox(html: myhtml, open: true);
    }, 1500);
});
```